# Using a node module within a Grunt Task fails

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, exif, exiftool

I'm trying to extract meta data from files read within a Grunt task.

executing: **node test.js** on this file:

```
var exif = require('exif2');

exif('fixtures/forest.png', function (err, o) {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

Produces the expected output

However, executing the grunt process: **grunt projectJSON**

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    var exif = require('exif2');
    return grunt.registerMultiTask("projectJSON", "Creates project JSON file.", function () {
        exif('fixtures/forest.png', function (err, o) {
            console.log(arguments);
        });
    });

}
```

** note that I am just testing with the **fixtures/forest.png** file

Produces no output whatsoever. The callback isn't even fired.

When I console.log exif, I get: [Function]

What am I missing? I think that the doesn't work is because of the grunt task, but I have no idea how to fix it. Wrapping it in a try-catch block produces nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your `projectJSON` task asynchronous - Grunt is exiting before your exif callback is being invoked.

Have a look at the [Grunt documentation on asynchronous tasks.](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#custom-tasks)

This is how you can make your task asynchronous:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    var exif = require('exif2');

    grunt.registerMultiTask("projectJSON", "Creates project JSON file.", function () {
        // Make task asynchronous.
        var done = this.async();

        exif('fixtures/forest.png', function (err, o) {
            console.log(arguments);

            // Invoke the task callback to continue with
            // other Grunt tasks.
            done();
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: oh mighty power of stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you Sly_cardinal! That makes sense -- Now I know why my task with ffmpeg isn't working.