# Node fs.readdir not working in Grunt file

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

When I ran my commands in Node command prompt, they worked fine.

```
fs= require('fs')
fs.readdir('.',function(e,files){console.log(files)})
```

However, when I inserted the lines above into my gruntfile.js, the callback function was not executed at all. Can you please tell me how I can get a list of files in a certain folder in Gruntfile.js?

Gruntfile.js:

```
'use strict';

var fs= require('fs');

module.exports= function(grunt){

    var configs = require('load-grunt-configs')(grunt);
    grunt.initConfig(configs);

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    fs.readdir('.', function(err,files){
        console.log(files);
    })


}
```

Comment: please provide the relevant Gruntfile code

Comment: I answered a similar question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28597314/retrieving-output-from-node-script-in-a-grunt-task/28597528?noredirect=1#comment45525856_28597528

Comment: @sctskw: It's actually not the answer. Sorry guy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the node file system working inside grunt, the task needs to be asynchronous . Here is the code:

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(grunt) {


  grunt.registerTask('showFiles', function() {
    var done = this.async(); // creating an async variable

    fs.readdir('.', function(err, files) {
      console.log(files);
      done(); // call when the task is done
    })
  })

  var files = fs.readdirSync('.');
  console.log('Showing Files Read Synchronously');
  console.log(files);
}
```

//output

```
▶ grunt showFiles
Showing Files Read Synchronously
[ 'Gruntfile.js', 'index.js', 'node_modules', 'test.js' ]
Running "showFiles" task
[ 'Gruntfile.js', 'index.js', 'node_modules', 'test.js' ]
```

Comment: fixed. didn't seem to affect it though :)

Comment: @sctskw: sorry mate. I got it now. Thanks so much :)

Comment: No problem. Select an answer if you're satisfied. Cheers